# How to compare and increment an atomic variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I want to know is it possible to perform comparison and increment of an atomic variable using a single atomic operation. This is what I have written so far(snippet code of a thread)

```
std::atomic<int> counter; //global variable

if(counter<25)
{
counter++;
}
else
{
     //send serial/socket data
}
```

I know that I am doing wrong since atomic variable counter is accessed two times(once for getting the data and other for increment). But this may cause a problem if another thread performs some update operation on 'counter' after getting the variable value and before increment. So I want to know is it possible to do both these operations in a single shot. Also I don't want to use mutex.

Comment: Your code example appears to show two different top-level variables that are both named `NoOfTimesSent`.  One of them is declared to be an `atomic<int>`, and the other is declared to be an `int`.  But it looks like you left out some code.  What goes where the `...`s are?

Comment: @james I have updated the question as per your request. Initially I will be setting the value of counter to 1 in main thread

Comment: @Harry Looking at your snippet it seems that you don't want to allow multiple threads to access either of the `if else` blocks. In that case I'm pretty sure that you'll need a mutex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `if(counter<25) counter++;` there is a race condition between reading the counter and updating it (i.e. an atomic load followed by atomic load-modify-store).

It needs a compare-exchange loop to make sure the value read has not changed since. If it has changed, the operation needs to be retried.

Something like the following:

```
std::atomic<int> counter;

auto value = counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
while(value < 25) {
    if(counter.compare_exchange_weak(value, value + 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed))
        break; // Succeeded incrementing counter.
    // compare_exchange_weak failed because counter has changed.
    // compare_exchange_weak reloaded value with the new value of counter.
    // Retry.
}
if(!(value < 25))
    // Failed to increment because counter is not less than 25.
```

Comment: Note that this may not be the exact equivalent code.
Think of CompareExchange as a way to check that the value you got before is still valid before writing the new value.

Comment: @GemTaylor Your statement is incorrect. You probably miss the fact that `compare_exchange_weak` loads the new value into its 1st argument if it has changed.

Comment: I am aware of that. It was the while loop I disliked. Yes, you might get away with it.

Comment: @GemTaylor I fail to make sense of what you wrote, sorry.

Comment: Consider also the OP's clause: 
else
{
     //send serial/socket data//
}

Comment: @GemTaylor If I understood correctly, the OP wanted to atomically increment the counter as long as it is less than 25. This code does that, however, if another thread changed it, the operation is retried.

Answer (score -1):

closer code might be "something like":

```
const int GUARD = 25;
auto value = counter.load()
if (value < GUARD)
{

    auto expectValue = value;
    auto newValue = expectValue + 1;
    for(;;)
    {
        if (counter.cmpxchg(expect,new))
        {    
             break;  // we did it!
        }
        newValue = expectValue + 1; 
        if (expectValue >= GUARD)
        {    
             break; // someone else did it!
        }
        // someone else incremented, now we increment again
        // cmpxchg updates expected with the new value
    }
    if (newValue <= GUARD)
    {
         // do the work you only want to do 25 times.
    }
}
```